# How to make sure canvas is of same size of video in html?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas, html5-video

I am displaying one local video and one remote video on the page. I am using this html page on the mobile. It is working fine. Now I have to draw on the local video using mouse (and using canvas). But we didn't specify the exact location of video elements. So unable to think how to render the canvas exactly over local video. Below are the files.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Realtime communication with WebRTC</h1>

  <div id="videos">
    <video id="localVideo" autoplay muted></video>
    <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay></video>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

video {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 320px;
}
```

Can any one please let me know how to overlay canvas exactly over localVideo. Canvas should be at the same position of localVideo and should be same size of localVideo.

Comment: Wrap the canvas and `#localVideo` in a div and position it with absolute positioning

Comment: In addition you can use video `loadeddata` event to get video intrinsic size and assign it to canvas.

Comment: I did that. But when I try to draw on canvas, it is not being drawn at correct position. But as the question is to make sure both sizes are same, I will resolve this and open new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) method to get the information about the position of the current element, and then use this information in order to position the canvas element.

Check the following example:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvasEl")
  const vid = document.getElementById("localVideo");
  const vidStyleData = vid.getBoundingClientRect();
  canvas.style.width = vidStyleData.width + "px";
  canvas.style.height = vidStyleData.height + "px";
  canvas.style.left = vidStyleData.left + "px";
  canvas.style.top = vidStyleData.top + "px";
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

video {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 320px;
}
canvas {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Realtime communication with WebRTC</h1>

  <div id="videos">
    <video id="localVideo" autoplay muted></video>
    <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay></video>
  </div>

<canvas id="canvasEl"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

> Note that I set the position of the canvas to `absolute` using the css. If you want you can do this with javascript as well.

Comment: 1
Partially working. I mean I wrote the code in event listener of onload, Canvas height is not same height as video height. Not problem with the solution. By the time onload event is received, width and height of video is 320 px and 160 px. But I think after the video is loaded, width and height of video is 320 px and 240 px

Comment: And when I draw a line at the right most end, it is not getting drawn.

Comment: In such case you can use the `play` event of the video (instead of the onload event of the document): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play_event This way you can change the size of the canvas only after the video started to play, and at that point you have the actual size of the video.

Comment: I did that. But when I try to draw on canvas, it is not being drawn at correct position. But as the question is to make sure both sizes are same, I will resolve this and open new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the X and Y position of the `<video>` element by using the `getBoundingClientRect()` method, also you can use both of the `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` properties to get its width and height.
Then you should add `position: absolute;` to the `<canvas>` element so you can set the values of the `top` and `left` properties.
Here is your code (inspect the code snippet it to see the difference!):

```js
let xPos = window.scrollX + document.querySelector('#localVideo').getBoundingClientRect().left;
let yPos = window.scrollY + document.querySelector('#localVideo').getBoundingClientRect().top;

document.getElementById('_canvas').style.left = xPos + "px";
document.getElementById('_canvas').style.top = yPos + "px";

document.getElementById('_canvas').style.width = document.querySelector('#localVideo').offsetWidth + "px";
document.getElementById('_canvas').style.height = document.querySelector('#localVideo').offsetHeight + "px";
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

video {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 320px;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Realtime communication with WebRTC</h1>

  <div id="videos">
    <video id="localVideo" autoplay muted></video>
    <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay></video>
  </div>

<canvas id="_canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Partially working. I mean I wrote the code in event listener of onload, Canvas height is not same height as video height. Not problem with the solution. By the time onload event is received, width and height of video is 320 px and 160 px. But I think after the video is loaded, width and height of video is 320 px and 240 px

Comment: And when I draw a line at the right most end, it is not getting drawn.